# Matplotlib and coordinate system

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

Until now I worked in the R environment and create the chart as the chart shown below.

```
library("rJava")
library("xlsxjars")
library("xlsx")
require(tidyr)
library("ggplot2")

df1<-data.frame(structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Group_1", "Group_2", 
                                                                                "Group_3"), class = "factor"), Country = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                     6L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 15L, 12L, 29L, 10L, 4L, 16L, 5L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
                                                                                                                                     13L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 9L, 30L, 31L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                     23L, 22L), .Label = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", 
                                                                                                                                                           "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", 
                                                                                                                                                           "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", 
                                                                                                                                                           "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", 
                                                                                                                                                           "North Macedonia", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", 
                                                                                                                                                           "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), 
               PCT_Direct_Tax = c(17.663, 6.048, 8.038, 29.092, 13.517, 
                                  7.409, 10.829, 10.155, 11.05, 13.904, 6.477, 14.184, 9.109, 
                                  7.41, 5.674, 16.528, 6.735, 13.56, 12.699, 13.562, 7.848, 
                                  10.145, 4.939, 7.866, 7.267, 16.231, 18.622, 14.213, 18.887, 
                                  17.741, 4.5), income_tax = c(104.760235996058, 101.665237369244, 
                                                               113.316015798358, 103.222974550114, 90.0358198452755, 84.2840209478504, 
                                                               80.9471275560435, 95.9558367315368, 98.6546600681184, 112.105602072378, 
                                                               102.667541663828, 90.3520755939945, 116.772956715611, 101.484483234044, 
                                                               93.3312408112594, 105.91143369624, 81.4327609978202, 96.9090350595422, 
                                                               108.112192891704, 93.6795560712191, 101.587464123904, 108.80182909181, 
                                                               86.071431257456, 87.5336162400315, 86.9970564933148, 105.33998752386, 
                                                               100.568081949912, 94.8944733487053, 98.6353656794101, 83.7358939227726, 
                                                               92.3836627060381), EU_28 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                                                                                            0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31L)))


ggplot(df1, aes(x=PCT_Direct_Tax, y=income_tax)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=5), shape=21, fill="lightblue")+
  geom_text(label=df1$Country, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = -1, check_overlap=T)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=median(df1$income_tax), linetype="dashed", color = "black")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=median(df1$PCT_Direct_Tax), linetype="dashed", color = "black")+
  geom_text(aes(x=median(median(df1$PCT_Direct_Tax)),y=max(df1$income_tax)), label="Median",hjust=1, size=4)+
  geom_text(aes(y=median(median(df1$income_tax)),x=max(df1$PCT_Direct_Tax)), label="Median",hjust=1, size=4)+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Now I want to start to work with Python and I want to make the same chart but with Matplotlib. I have already converted data into Python syntax, but I am not so proficient user of Matplotlib.

```
data = {
         'Country': ["Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", 
         "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", 
          "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", 
          "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", 
          "North Macedonia", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", 
          "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom"],
         'PCT_Direct_Tax':[17.663, 6.048, 8.038, 29.092, 13.517, 
                                  7.409, 10.829, 10.155, 11.05, 13.904, 6.477, 14.184, 9.109, 
                                  7.41, 5.674, 16.528, 6.735, 13.56, 12.699, 13.562, 7.848, 
                                  10.145, 4.939, 7.866, 7.267, 16.231, 18.622, 14.213, 18.887, 
                                  17.741, 4.5],
         'income_tax':[104.760235996058, 101.665237369244, 
                                                               113.316015798358, 103.222974550114, 90.0358198452755, 84.2840209478504, 
                                                               80.9471275560435, 95.9558367315368, 98.6546600681184, 112.105602072378, 
                                                               102.667541663828, 90.3520755939945, 116.772956715611, 101.484483234044, 
                                                               93.3312408112594, 105.91143369624, 81.4327609978202, 96.9090350595422, 
                                                               108.112192891704, 93.6795560712191, 101.587464123904, 108.80182909181, 
                                                               86.071431257456, 87.5336162400315, 86.9970564933148, 105.33998752386, 
                                                               100.568081949912, 94.8944733487053, 98.6353656794101, 83.7358939227726, 
                                                               92.3836627060381],
        }
```

So can anybody help me with how to make this chart in `Matplotlib`?

Comment: A blanket request to reproduce a plot is not helpful to the rest of the community.  Please read https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py, make a start, and come to us with specific problems.

Comment: You might also look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html

Comment: When I drop the 'data' object into the python3 terminal, I get an error `SyntaxError: unmatched '}'` is that expected (or have I messed something up)?

Comment: @stevec On my PC is work. I also tried with copy paste from here and also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Result]**This is what i got using your provided data, not exactly the same**

```
# Importing libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
# plotting scatter plot
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.scatter(data["PCT_Direct_Tax"], data["income_tax"])

plt.axvline(np.quantile(data["PCT_Direct_Tax"], 0.5), c='b', label='Median PCT_Direct_Tax')
plt.axhline(np.quantile(data["income_tax"], 0.5), c='r', label='Median income_tax')

# Loop for annotation of all points
for i in range(len(data["income_tax"])):
    plt.annotate(data["Country"][i], (data["PCT_Direct_Tax"][i], data["income_tax"][i] + 0.2))
plt.xlabel("PCT_Direct_Tax")
plt.ylabel("income_tax")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```